# asp.net core 2.x - where and how to place central controller function?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core application with various controllers.
I now want to add a central function, that does e.g. an access logging (store some information’s in a SQL datatable).
This can be done by a central function and some logic over the session variables, but then, the function has to be called from every possible entry point (controller function), what is not nice.

- **Is there a central point, where such a function can be called (by
  every controller call, no matter which controller/ controller
  function was called)?**

**Edit:**

The hint of @Y.Y. (as comment) was useful.

The following code in the central function:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

contained in Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
   {
    await ZF.CheckHilfstabellenAsync();
    await next.Invoke();
    });
```

whereby ZF.CheckHilfstabellenAsync(); is my central function
seems to do the job... (seems to be called now by every controller call).
But I have to investigate it in detail now (especially regarding performance and possible side effects).
I'm not sure, if this is a good idea (as I also have Ajax calls with JS, where the function not should be called)...
But.., it seems as this answers my question (possible solution)

Comment: You can perhaps achieve this through your own middleware. But I am not sure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: You can also use a [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on select actions or controllers. To get this into all of your controllers you can add the filter to your own base controller then use this as the base for the other controllers in your app.

Comment: I had a (short) look also to the filters in the meantime. Seems to be more complex as the code in my example. I go with the my example code for now and investigate it in detail (especially regarding performance, as the function really is called by EVERY controller call). If I find the time (and don't forget;-), I will post my findings here...